# The installed package is incompatible in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

We are developing a small game application using Xamarin forms in visual studio 2019. When I try to install the app in android tab 6.0 while I am getting an error "The installed package is incompatible. Please manually uninstall and try again.". Please give me a solution to resolve this issue

Note: Previously I unstalled app(Settings->Apps->myapp)

Comment: This is to inform you that I just factory reset my device after I can able to deploy. Anyway thanks for the reply-SomeStudent

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

- See if updating Xamarin will help
- rebuild/clean solution
- close VS -> delete the bin and obj folders in your Xamarin Android project-> relaunch

The last step is usually what I have to do when Xamarin complains about having two versions of itself installed in one of my work projects since one of our branches has a brand new .csproj design so it is incompatible with the previous one

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After get this Deployment Fail,

**Steps=>**

1. Open the Command Prompt in ada.exe

[image]

2.Run the **adb devices** command and after that you can see the listed devices

[image]

3. After that run command **adb uninstall**  then solved the problem

[image]